# Email Sent But Not Receiving

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I am facing issue in Symfony Swiftmailer to send mail.

By Using command:

```html
php app/console swiftmailer:email:send
```

I got following output as "Sent 1 emails", but I did not received.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vARWf.png)

Answer (score 2):

Swift Mailer needs a properly configured SMTP server on the local machine to effectively send the mail.
For development purpose, you can use [MailCatcher](https://mailcatcher.me/) to get a working local SMTP server and check if mails are sent correctly.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use fake smtp server to debug emails in dev environment

I use https://mailtrap.io/ they have free plan that is enough

disclaimer: I don't work for them nor I'm affiliated in any way, just happy user :)

Comment: It often does not get emails when I need to test. Just debugged in symfony - email shows sent 1, not appearing in mailtrap. It is really annoying. I do not know if it is symfony or mailtrap also. From curl example it receives email when I send. But then symfony should show some error if there is some fault.